# How to animate gridview.builder in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm new to Flutter and Dart and still learning them.

I need to make animation to the coloured circles grid as in the following gif:

[image: Grid view animation]

I searched a lot online with no result.

Here is the code that I'm working on:

```
child: GridView.builder(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount: colorsList.length,
                                    gridDelegate:
                                        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                            childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                                            crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                                            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                                            crossAxisCount: 5),
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      var color = colorsList[index];
                                      return MaterialButton(
                                          elevation: 0,
                                          color: color,
                                          shape: CircleBorder(),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                            setState(() {
                                              AnimatedList(
                                                itemBuilder: (context, index,
                                                    animation) {
                                                  return SlideTransition(
                                                      position: animation
                                                          .drive(List<color>));
                                                },
                                              );
                                              mainColor = color;
                                            });
                                          });
                                    },
                                  ),
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

use [auto_animated](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/auto_animated),

```
    Widget buildAnimatedItem(
      BuildContext context,
      int index,
      Animation<double> animation,
    ) {
      var color = colorsList[index];
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: Tween<double>(
          begin: 0,
          end: 1,
        ).animate(animation),
        child: SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: Offset(0, -0.1),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(animation),
          child: MaterialButton(
                                      elevation: 0,
                                      color: color,
                                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                        setState(() {
                                          AnimatedList(
                                            itemBuilder: (context, index,
                                                animation) {
                                              return SlideTransition(
                                                  position: animation
                                                      .drive(List<color>));
                                            },
                                          );
                                          mainColor = color;
                                        });
                                      }),
        ),
      );
    }

LiveGrid.options(
  options: options,
  itemBuilder: buildAnimatedItem,
  itemCount: itemsCount,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                                        crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                                        mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                                        crossAxisCount: 5),
);
```

OR

this might help, [flutter_staggered_animations](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_animations):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  int columnCount = 3;

  return Scaffold(
    body: AnimationLimiter(
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: columnCount,
        children: List.generate(
          100,
          (int index) {
            return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(
              position: index,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
              columnCount: columnCount,
              child: ScaleAnimation(
                child: FadeInAnimation(
                  child: YourListChild(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, can you please embed the code into my code? I tried many times, and every time the output appears distorted.

Comment: updated with another option (combined your code)

Comment: The console throwed an error: ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building NewCounter(dirty, state: _NewCounterState#ba01e):
Class '_NewCounterState' has no instance method 'build' with matching arguments.
Receiver: Instance of '_NewCounterState'
Tried calling: build(Instance of 'StatefulElement')
Found: build(BuildContext) => Widget

Comment: here is the full code inside new_counter.dart https://justpaste.it/5xacp. Help me!

Comment: auto_animated looks to be pretty much abandoned - I'd use flutter_animate.